# Inherited class references base class' values

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public int myId;
    public string commonField1;
    public string commonField2;
    public string commonField3;
    public string changeable;
    public List<ChildClass> children;

    public ParentClass(int id)
    {
        myId = myId;
    }

    public createChildren()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) 
        {
            children.Add(new ChildClass(id));
        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass(int id) : base (id) 
    {
        myId = myId;
        changeable = "new";
    }
}
```

Because `ChildClass` only exists in the context of it's ParentClass, and there will be 999999 children. That is creating `999999` copies of all the `commonField`'s when in reality it just needs a reference to it's parent. The only real thing a `ChildClass` needs to store besides references is `changeable`.

How can this be accomplished?

I am almost thinking a better approach when I need the children is just to make 999999 shallow copies of the ParentClass and just change the 999999 changeable fields. Shallow copies will have references to `commonField1` or would it deep copy values?

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using inheritance at all. It sounds like a child isn't really a parent - it just needs a *reference* to a parent. Why did you make Child extend Parent in the first place? Does `changeable` need to be in `Parent` at all? We really don't have enough context to suggest other code at the moment...

Comment: yes `changeable` needs to be in `Parent`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Why is `ChildClass` derived from `ParentClass` if you only use two common fields. Shouldn't you rather derive from a common interface or base class that only contains the common fields? I think you are confusing wrapping and inheritance.

Comment: I have learned about base/derived classes not about interfaces (yet). Will google interfaces and see if thats better

Comment: If `ChildClass` _really_ "is a" `ParentClass` then it, too, will have a list of children, each of which will have a list of children, etc.  I agree that it seems like inheritance is not the right solution.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet has it right. Maybe I just need a reference to the parent and then when `ChildClass.commonField*` is GET or SET, I need it to GET or SET the Parent of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have one thing right, thats a *lot* of repeated data if `commonFieldX` is truly unchanging.

I see several solutions:

1. **Prefer Composition over Inheritance**

   Why are you inheriting at all? If there is no polymorphic behavior, then just pass the base class instance to the 10000 children and call it good:

   ```
   public createChildren()
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
            children.Add(new ChildClass(id, this));
       }
   }

   public class ChildClass
   {
        public ChildClass(int id, ParentClass parent) : base (id) 
        {
              myId = myId; //This shouldn't be part of the base class?
              changeable = "new"; //Same here
              myParent = parent;
        }
   }
   ```
2. **Share those variables among all instances**

   `static` members belong to the "global" instance, so they won't be recreated for each derived object:

   ```
   public class ParentClass
   {
       public int MyId {get; set;}
       public static string CommonField1 {get; set;}
       public static string CommonField2 {get; set;}
       public static string CommonField3 {get; set;}
       public string Changeable {get; set;}
   ```

   Note that some of this should likely be `protected` instead of `public` and you should *always* expose public fields via properties instead of directly. Of course, if you have multiple instances of `ParentClass` that have differing values of those fields, this is a no-go.

Comment: 1.) How would I do ChildClass.commonField1 ?
2.) ParentClass does have differing values.

Comment: @LearningJrDev 1) Either expose the parent instance as a property (e.g. `c.Parent.CommonField1`) or create pass-through properties.  Note that pass-through properties are generally a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

If child and parent should have some relation (i.e. common parent class to share methods/properties), but child need to share properties with parent you can redirect properties request to parent (note that it would men getting property of deeply nested child is very slow):

```
public class Node
{
    public virtual string Field {get {return parent != null ? parent.Field : field;}}

    public Node parent;
    public List<Node> children;

    public Node()
    {
        children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public createChildren()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) 
        {
            children.Add(new ChildNode(i, this));
        }
    }
}

public class ChildNode : Node
{
    public override string Field {get {return parent.Field;}}
    public ChildNode(Node parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

public class RootNode : Node
{
    public override string Field {get {return "Root";}}
    public RootNode()
    {
        this.parent = null;
    }
}
```